# Does empty enumeration in C structure creates unnamed field?

Tags: ida, decompilation, c

I was parsing some modified C++ headers with IDA when I come to some strange behavior. Imagine we have a structure like this (stored in a C header):

```
struct S
{
    enum {EN0, EN1};

    int m1;
} ;
```

When I parse it with IDA Pro the created type seems to threat the first unnamed enum as data member inside the structure. I'm thinking - is this correct behavior in the case?

I tested this on online C compiler which seems not to count the enumeration inside `struct S` as part of its data ([here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/AwbLoM0eUkZ9zfdl) - i tested sizeof of `S` when there is only enum in it and it gave size of 0).

Answer (score 3):

It's just a definition of an ENUM there is no declaration.

Try this:

```
struct S
{
    enum {EN0, EN1} myEnum;

    int m1;
} ;
```

Now we have two ints.